# Angular 8 build - rest end point issue

Tags: angular

we migrated server side code to microservice and front end we are using angular 8 application. The issue is dynamic rest end point URL. E.g. development set up they will provide the url 'http://sample.com/restendpoint' and sanity enviornment 'http://devsanity.com/restendpoint'. Not sure where they hosted the rest end points is there any way to provide this URL dynamically during angular build process and injected in specifc enviornment file ?

Comment: If it's provided during build then it's hardly dynamic.  Anyway, you absolutely can do this but how you would go about it depends on your tool chain.  Additional information is absolutely required.

Comment: Thanks for reply not sure about the best practices. If i directly added in environment.prod.ts or enviornment.ts file then not sure in sanity or testing environment which URL we need to provide. Currently consider we only build app using angular cli.

Comment: You need another target in `angular.json` and a corresponding file like `environment.sanity.ts`

Comment: yes that i understand we can provided in angular.json file. The main q for URL where we need to provide in angular.json file and how it can pick up and injected in envrionment.ts file.